# Xcode 10.2, iOS 12.2 : Application installed over OTA(Enterprise) not opening

Tags: xcode, ios12, ota

I have converted my web application into .ipa file using cordova. It was working well until the iPad is updated to iOS12. But since then, the app crashes even before launching.

I tried everything, having searched through various posts of stackoverflow, inlcuding

cleaning, 
creating new provisional profile, 
ensuring the .plist file contents,
changing code signing entity,
changing architecture in build settings, 
redo everything from scratch
and etc.,

I have even created a new helloworld application from scratch. In Xcode, Product -> Run is working fine. But when I archived .ipa file through enterprise option, it does not work when I open Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Install.

FYI. I have tried with different deployment targets from iOS 9 to iOS12.2

Please help. Thank you so much.
Seyed Ismail.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? It doesn't install, or once installed, it doesn't open?

Comment: It is installed, it doesn't open. Open for half a second and closed.